# excel vb ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Fill runtime error

Tags: excel, charts, vba

```
rgb1 = 200
rgb2 = 200
rgb3 = 200

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(rgb1, rgb2, rgb3)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

When I record a macro in Excel 2010 the above is what I get when right clicking on the chart area which is the outer most portion of the chart.  This is the area outside of `ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select`.

However when i try to use the above code in my data plotting macro it then fails with `runtime error '-2147024809 (80070057)': the item with the specified name wasn't found`

I am stuck with the `("Chart 1")` part.
I can have any number of charts already created in excel, having any kind of name, whenever I record a macro on it results in the same macro code.

In excel visual basic, how can I change the chart area background color to a specified rgb value for the active chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `With ActiveChart.ChartArea.Format.Fill` as follows...

```
rgb1 = 200
rgb2 = 200
rgb3 = 200

With ActiveChart.ChartArea.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(rgb1, rgb2, rgb3)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```